# AJAX php header returning null in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I'm setting a header in php using header('page-title: "200"'), and when i try to access it in javascript, I get a null. I don't really know what code I can provide to show you, but I doubt it matters since it works fine and returns with "200" on my localhost, but doesn't work on the remote server. 
I'm sure it's just me making a stupid mistake. 
Thanks,
Josh

EDIT here's the javascript

```
function RequestPage(url, push){
    //load new page 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(xhr.readyState === 4){
            content.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            AttachLinkClickHandlers(content);

            document.title = "Delivery Duck // " + xhr.getResponseHeader('Page-Title');

            document.body.setAttribute("class", xhr.getResponseHeader('Page-Title'));

            EvalScripts();

            if(push){
                history.pushState(url, document.title, url);
            }
        }   
    };

    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Only", 1);    
    xhr.send();
}
```

its the xhr.getResponseHeader() that fails to work on the remote server.

The php :

```
$content_only = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_ONLY']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_ONLY'] == 1);
if($content_only){
    header('Page-Title: ' . $page_title); 
}
```

Comment: How are you accessing it in javascript?

Comment: Well, we kind of need the javascript (assuming ajax?). It may be how it was setup and how its interpreting the return.

Comment: ok, editing question to include it